# resetting form after php submit

Tags: php, forms

I am using a simple html form as a contact, and when fields and submitted the form does not clear the fields.

this is my php
I read online in few places and I've learned that I have to use the .reset , but I am not familiar with php a lot. I am not sure where would I add the .reset and how.

```
<?
$name  = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$msg   = $_REQUEST["msg"];
$to    = "example@example.com";
if (isset($email) && isset($name) && isset($msg)) {
    $subject = "Message / Closure Film";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" ;
$msg     = "Name: $name:<br/> Email: $email <br/>  Message: $msg";

   $mail =  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
  if($mail)
    {
        echo 'success';

    }

else
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}

?>
```

my html

```
<div id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid PageHead">
      <div class="span12">
        <h3>CONTACT US<span> <img src="images/underline.png" alt="______"></span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="row-fluid ContactUs">
      <div  class="span6 offset3">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="phpcontactform">
          <div class="control-group">
            <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name">
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <input class="input-block-level" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <textarea class="input-block-level" rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" id="message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <p>
              <input class="btn btn-danger btn-large" type="submit" value="Send Message">
            </p>
            <span class="loading"></span> </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

added this to the head of my html, but didnt get any result

```
<script type="javascript">

$('#phpcontactform').trigger("reset");

</script>
```

Comment: What does the code look like for your form?

Comment: `reset` is for arrays in PHP. Are you talking about jQuery's `.reset()` function?

Comment: yes .reset() function.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  If the form is actually POSTed, the form fields would automatically be reset on the subsequent page load unless you are specifically filling in the form field values in some manner. Is there some javascript (AJAX) form posting functionality that you are not showing?

Comment: The form 'action' is default, which means submitting to the same page. It should clear itself. Can you setup an example on jsfiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Thank you for all the guidance, I just used another contact.php that I had and was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#phpcontactform')[0].reset();
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if you're trying to do an ajax submit and keep the user on the page, or just submit the form. But the line you're looking for is `$("#phpcontactform")[0].reset();`, you could wrap that in a `$(document).ready()` if you needed to!